# How to use the same Redux store in separate components, where there is no common root component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm attempting to set up a redux store that is accessible from multiple components. I'm new to this, but I understand that normally one would wrap the root app component with the provider to make the same store context available everywhere.

However, I'm working within a legacy app, where we're tacking on React components here and there and there's no site-wide common root app component, only separate components trees that know nothing about each other. I thought a redux store would be a good solution to this, but now realize that there's some context handling going on behind the scenes and I'm not sure how to wire up each provider with the same context. I found some basic info on [providing a context](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#providing-custom-context), but I'm not sure if this solves my problem or not and it's getting into the weeds, especially using Typescript.

Specifically, I have a mini-cart in the header and several pages that want to interact with that component. I have things working on both sides, but they are affecting different stores.

MiniCart.tsx:

```
import store from '../../common/stores/store';
...
<Provider store={store}>
    <MiniCart />
</Provider>
```

PageThatNeedsToAddToMiniCart.tsx:

```
import store from '../../common/stores/store';
...
<Provider store={store}>
    <PageThatNeedsToAddToMiniCart />
</Provider>
```

--- EDIT 1 ---

hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch
const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch
const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

export { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector }
```

miniCartSlice.tsx:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type { RootState } from './store';

interface MiniCart {
    SubTotal: number;
}

interface MiniCartState {
    SubTotal: number;
}

const initialState: UserCart = {
    SubTotal: 0,
}

const miniCartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'miniCart',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        productAdded: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserCart>) => {
            return state = action.payload;
        }
    }
});

const selectSubTotal = (state: RootState) => state.miniCart.SubTotal;

export const { productAdded } = miniCartSlice.actions;
export { selectSubTotal };
export default miniCartSlice.reducer;
```

store.tsx:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import miniCartReducer from './miniCartSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        miniCart: miniCartReducer
    }
})

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export type { RootState, AppDispatch }
export default store;
```

PageThatNeedsToAddToMiniCart.tsx:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
...

dispatch(
    productAdded(result.UpdatedCart)
);
```

MiniCart.tsx:

```
//This value is not updated when the other component dispatches "productAdded". I expected it to trigger a rerender.
const subTotal = useAppSelector(selectSubTotal); 
...
return (
    <div> 
        <p>{`Subtotal: ${subTotal} `}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what I'm seeing debugging, but the two components appear to access separate stores.

--- EDIT 2 ---

It turns out that, while I'm configuring the store once, bundling the apps separately results in separate stores. I ended up going with Jacob's answer for simplicity, but may end up going with his more robust suggestion of [redux-micro-frontend](https://github.com/microsoft/redux-micro-frontend) down the road.

Comment: Redux by itself has no connection to React, the connection is handled by React-Redux. What this means for you is it's possible to create your store external to either of your react apps and then pass that same store to both apps. This will allow both react apps to update based on actions/state updates triggered by the other.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need to be doing. Can you possibly give me a simple example of how that might look or point me in the direction of some documentation?

Comment: Isn't what Jacob is describing already what you are doing with the code examples you provided? A `Provider` component provides a `store` object to the sub-ReactTree it is wrapping? What exactly is the issue with what you are trying to do here? What isn't working? Is the issue that "I have things working on both sides, but they are affecting ***different*** stores." - you should have one single app store if you are wanting any consumers to read/update the same state.

Comment: Because of the way the (legacy) app is structured, I can't wrap the root with a provider because they are completely separate, so these two components are working with different stores (at least that's what I believe I'm seeing when debugging). I think Jacob is referring to manually wiring things up using the `connect()` API, but I'm struggling with that.

Comment: The `connect` Higher Order Component only connects a component to the nearest `Provider` component providing the store. I guess what I'm asking is if the issue is because you are using two different app stores. What I think both Jacom and I are suggesting is to pass the ***same*** store to both providers. Does that make sense?

Comment: I edited my question with my store and how I'm importing it to pass to each component. Am I wrong to assume this is resulting in separate stores?

Comment: Looks like the exported `store` reference is the same for any consumers that import it. It's only configured once ***then*** exported.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm just doing things wrong - I assumed I'm dealing with different stores based on debugging. I edited with the rest of the relevant files and a stripped down slice definition.

Comment: Even if you are using the same imported file if you are bundling your apps separately you will most likely end up with two stores. A dodgy test for this would be to just attach a reference of the store to the window for each app, such as window.APP_A_STORE and window.APP_B_STORE, and then manually check their reference equality once the apps have rendered (window.APP_A_STORE === window.APP_B_STORE).

Comment: You're correct that I'm bundling the apps separately - I ran your test and the equality check is indeed false. It's good to know that if I were to somehow bundle them together, I'd be using the same store, although I'm not sure if it's possible (we're using webpack - maybe it's simpler than I'm thinking, but I'm not very familiar with this stuff). I'll play around with it tomorrow.

Comment: I was playing around with a hacky solution around storing it globally, like on the window object, before trying Redux. I think it would work, but I'd hate to go that route.

Comment: You could look at something like [redux-micro-frontend](https://github.com/microsoft/redux-micro-frontend) and adjust your stores to fit in it's pattern. Otherwise like you mentioned you would need someway to share the store, i.e. on the window. I'll post another possible option which avoids the sharing it directly on the window, but still a bit of a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create 3 separate bundles (App A, App B and Store) you could share the store via an event.

**App A**

```
// Wait to start the application until the store is created.
window.addEventListener('createStore', function(event) {
    const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);

    // pull store from the event details
    const store = event.detail;

    root.render(
        <StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppA />
            </Provider>
        </StrictMode>
    )
});
```

**App B**

```
// Wait to start the application until the store is created.
window.addEventListener('createStore', function(event) {
    const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);

    // pull store from the event details
    const store = event.detail;

    root.render(
        <StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppB />
            </Provider>
        </StrictMode>
    )
});
```

**Store**

```
// Wait for page to load (might be needed so that when the react 
// applications respond to the custom event the DOM elements that
// they target are definitely created).
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    const reducer = /* CONFIGURE ROOT REDUCER HERE */;
    const initialState = /* CONFIGURE INITIAL STATE HERE */;
    const middleware = /* CONFIGURE INITIAL MIDDLEWARE HERE */;
    
    // Create redux store.
    const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, middleware)
    
    // Create custom event with reference to store attached.
    const createStoreEvent = new CustomEvent('createStore', { detail: store });
    
    // dispatch createStore event
    window.dispatchEvent(createStoreEvent);
});
```

While this is pretty similar to just slapping the store on the window, it is slightly harder to grab the store reference (can't just start typing `window.` in the console and see what pops up).